# Bank treating loan as asset

Tags: loans, assets

I understand bank treat loan as asset but isn't it the cash reserve being transferred from bank to borrower, resulting in reduction of cash reserve of bank and hence reducing its lending power.

From investopedio an asset is a resource with economic value that an individual, corporation, or country owns or controls with the expectation that it will provide a future benefit.

But when spoken about loans especially unsecured loans there is only outflow of cash and inflow is interest plus loan amount over a period of time. So treating the unsecured loan amount deposited in borrower's account as asset before being recovered seems confusing as there is nothing except the entry into ledger that bank has lend the amount which has no value as it is for such a record in generating liquidity at required time.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions which contain 'counterpoints' within the question itself. It is clear that you feel there is a frequent 'misunderstanding' within the financial community [clearly related to your belief in cryptocurrencies], but this isn't really a great way to 'challenge' what you perceive as misunderstandings. In simplest form, if you think that a question you ask would get the 'wrong' answer form users here, instead of burying your 'counterpoints' within your question itself, you should add your own answer as a separate piece from your question. This is the SE way of things

Comment: I am asking lot of question not out of intention to raise alarm. But to see how the so called financial concepts which is a black box for people not related to financial system really can relate to in simple terms.

Comment: The answers from the community has really changed my understanding of money matters. All these while I was thinking that bank which attracts more number of deposits would indeed feel wealthy. But upon deeper decoding I was informed it treats deposits as a liability rather than asset.

Comment: I'm not sure you're fully there yet - if a bank has $1B in deposits, then it is true that it also owes that money back, but in the meantime having more deposits allows it to lend out more money to *other* people, and it receives more interest than it pays out (because you pay more interest on a mortgage than you get back from a bank in your savings account, right)? So yes, banks do want more deposits - it isn't "free money" to them as they need to pay it back, but it does give them the ability to earn money on this "interest rate differential".

Answer (score 6):

Before lending some of your money out you have the money. That's an asset. After you lend the money out, you no longer have the money but you have a different asset: the fact that someone has promised to repay you the money and pay you interest. Exactly what that asset is worth is, well, complicated. It's worth more than cash because it will get you interest. But then again it's worth less than cash because there's a chance the borrower will default. This is why banks charge higher interest rates to riskier customers: they want the "higher" and "lower" to balance out so that overall, a loan of 10K is worth slightly more than just having 10K on hand.

Calling the loan an asset even though it involved money leaving your reserves is no different than calling a car or a work of art an asset. Money left your hands to acquire it, but acquire it you have and it is worth something to you. That's an asset.

Answer (score 0):

A loan is an asset, not just to a bank but to any business.  It is the same as an account receivable in that it anticipates the value of future cash flow from repayment.  Thus it holds implied value (no differently than cash, since currency only has value so long as its issuer can make good on their obligations, thereby creating a trust relationship between the issuer and the party willing to accept it as a medium of exchange).  It only becomes a liability (or a "non-performing asset") when the borrower fails to make the payments.

In the sense that a loan impairs a bank's capital reserve, you would be right not to see it as an asset.